Transfer SOL out of PDA owned wallet account
Basically I'm trying to figure out to transfer SOL out of a wallet account which is owned by a PDA. the PDA is in turn owned by my program.
I've tried invoke_signed, my seeds are all correct, and I keep getting signer escalation on the wallet account pubkey itself when trying to transfer that way. I understand that system program transfer function requires the account where lamports are being sent from to be a signer.
And the method that uses try borrow mut lamports also doesnt work because the program isnt the owner of the wallet account, the PDA is. I'm really stuck, does anyone know how to do this?
creating the pda:
invoke_signed(
            &system_instruction::create_account(
                initializer.key,
                pda_account.key,
                lamports,
                space as u64,
                program_id,
            ),
            &[initializer.clone(), pda_account.clone(), system_program.clone()],
            &[&[seed.as_bytes(), initializer.key.as_ref(), &[bump]]],
        )?;

assigning ownership to the pda:
            let instruction = system_instruction::assign(&initializer.key, pda_account.key);
        invoke(
            &instruction,
            &[initializer.clone(), pda_account.clone()],
        )?;

when trying to transfer lamports from the initializer to the pda via "try_borrow_mut_lamports", it doesnt work. Neither does using an invoke_signed transfer instruction.
**wallet_account.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= lamports_to_transfer;
**_pda_account.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += lamports_to_transfer;

when using "invoke_signed" transfer, I get a signer escalation error, the runtime thinks the wallet_account should have signed the transaction, but it cant as i dont have access to the users keys to sign on the frontend.
let lamports_to_transfer = wallet_account.lamports();

let ix = system_instruction::transfer(
    wallet_account.key,
    pda_account.key,
    lamports_to_transfer,
);

invoke_signed(
    &ix,
    &[ wallet_account.clone(), pda_account.clone() system_program.clone()],
    &[&[seed.as_bytes(), &wallet_account.key.as_ref(), &[bump3]]],
)?;

shouldnt signing it with the PDA seeds be enough?
I am certain i am deriving the keys correctly, i have msg!'s littered throughout to debug line by line.
is this even possible?

**from_account.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= amount_of_lamports;
**to_account.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += amount_of_lamports;
where from_account is your PDA

if this does not work, could you please share your code where you are trying to this along with the context for the instruction?

I get the "instruction spent from the balance of an account it does not own" error. this is because the PDA is the owner of the wallet, which was done with 'assign' instruction after the user creates a PDA. When running this instruction, the transaction is signed by the program itself. Now I want to transfer sol from the PDA owned wallet account. does that make sense? invoke_signed doesnt work either.

hmm, can you share your full instruction code here?

i updated my post with the relevant code / notes. hoping to get any clarification. is it proper etiquette to assign wallet ownership to pda?

what is the wallet account? can you share the context as well for this instruction?

wallet account would just be a regular user wallet. wallet_account is a previous initializer, like one created in phantom. but in this case the ownership of this wallet is the PDA.

ah ok, that’s why you cannot do this. you are trying to transfer from some user owned wallet. it would be the equivalent of me being able to take funds from any wallet. what you could do is take them from the signer if wallet_account is the signer

it doesnt matter that the wallet is owned by the pda?

hmm there might be some misunderstanding. a “wallet” and a PDA are both accounts owned by the system program. inherently they are the same entity. so it is not really possible for a wallet to own a PDA. however, a program can “own” a PDA.

suggestion, have a “vault PDA” that the wallet account deposits X sol to. then the program can transfer funds from “vault PDA” to whoever

I think youre confused. the PDA has ownership over the wallet in this scenario. I did this with the assign function above. I thought this was possible?

ah, ok. you are making the authority of the pda the wallet account. so you need to build the transaction with the wallet account as the fee payer, and sign the transaction with the wallet_account in the front end. you cannot sign on behalf of the wallet account in the program if the wallet_account is not a PDA owned/created by the program.

i am making the authority of the wallet account the PDA. You keep saying that the wallet has ownership over the PDA. my program has ownership over the PDA, and the PDA has ownership over the wallet. The wallet is owned by the PDA. i dont know how many different ways i can say it, the wallet is no longer owned by the system program. but the pda that was generated. is it still the same case?

If I understand correctly, there is Wallet A which is a wallet owned by some human. you want to transfer funds from Wallet A. to do so, you created a PDA to take authority over Wallet A, so you could “manage” user A’s funds. is this correct?

yeah thats the scenaro im in. i guess im going about it wrong

Correct. ok, that was my confusion. I thought you accidentally mixing up verbiage. this is not possible. if it was, anyone could very easily take anyone’s wallet balances of anything. suggestion - program has a PDA “user vault” +  as seed. User deposits funds into their personal vault/pda for you/your program to manage.

if you don’t mind accepting this answer if you think it does answer the question asked so future users can quickly see how to transfer sol from PDA’s. Let me know if you have any other questions about anything :)

I believe the appropriate answer for my question, would be that it is impossible. in that case though it begs to question, why is it possible to update a wallets ownership then if all it does is brick the wallet? you cant assign a deployed program to be the owner, nor another wallet, only a PDA.

haha yah, fair point. I think it’s up to the developer/user to make good choices and/or write sound programs. In the same way I could change the seed for my wallet not write seeds down, and throw my computer in the trash. dumb and silly, but this I could do this tho. or I could write a program that burns all your wallet’s sol when you sign X transaction. the whole ethos of “don’t trust, verify”. No one is preventing you from doing anything on blockchain, which is rad in so many ways, but does require people be smart.

hmm. i guess i just figured that if it was available then it would do something. but i guess what im trying to do i possible through a different avenue. apologies, im new to solana sdk. so i guess it was confusing me

maybe it would help to think about “user wallets” as literal wallets people have in their back pocket. Imagine each persons wallet has 100$ cash. Now, if I could create a device that magically could take all cash every wallet, that would be scary (what you were trying to do). However, If I want to open a bank account and deposit my cash with Solana Bank to manage my 100$, I walk in and give them my $100 + sign a form giving them permission (sign the transaction in program to send my money to PDA), this makes sense. The bank is your program.

  &system_instruction::create_account(
                initializer.key,
                pda_account.key,
                lamports,
                space as u64,
                ***program_id***,
            ),

The problem is in the owner field specified in the account creation. You assigned your "program_id" as the account's owner. Then, you invoke another program(The Solana Token program, using &system_instruction::create_aqccount) to perform an action on an account it doesn't own.
To fix this, you would have to manually debit the account and credit another account the same amount of lamports so the total account balance before and after the transaction would be the same. like so
**account_one.lamports.borrow_mut() -= <amount_in_lamports>;
**account_two.lamports.borrow_mut() += <amount_in_lamports>;;
This would act as your program performing actions on an account it owns. But for more security, you'd want to do this rarely and use the token program instruction to interact with native SOL accounts.
